# Hibernate result convert List object array to String array

Tags: hibernate

I have hibernate code as below which returns me a List which contains `Object[]` something like `List<Object[]>`. But I need to pass this List to another method which accepts a type of `List<String[]>`. How can convert a `List<Object[]>` to `List<String[]>`. I don't want to iterate again all the records to convert back. Anyone has an idea about how to do directly in Hibernate (or) a better way without iterating

```
List reports = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    reports = session.createSQLQuery(weeklyReport).list();
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception occurred in repository", e);
                } finally {
                    if (null != session) {
                        session.close();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: In my experience, I usually declare my list with the type I want. I think it allows you to cast the query results to a typed collection. If not, you can always use reports.addAll (session.createSQLQuery(weeklyReport).list()); since it accepts a Collection.

Comment: There is no way. But you could make the other method accept a List<Object[]> instead.

Comment: I cannot change another method.